# Reading spaces with sscanf

Tags: c, string, file, space, scanf

I am trying to read a string using `sscanf` in order to use this scanned string as the name of the file when I split it.

The problem is that the `sscanf` only reads until the first space present in the file, what happens normally. However, I saw here in Stack Overflow many tips about how make it reads these spaces.

Unfortunately, all of them seem to be the same thing, just add a `%[^\t\n\0]` or anything like this to the function.

The problem is that this approach is not working for me and I cannot identify why; I tried all of the tips I found here and none of them is working.

If someone could help me identifying the problem I would appreciate.

Here is the code:

```
int TAM_BUFFER = 75; 
int filecounter=1, linecounter=1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char fileoutputname[15];
    char buffer[TAM_BUFFER];
    char buffer2[15];
    char buffer3[15];

    FILE *arquivo = fopen("Entrada.txt", "r");
    FILE *saida;

    sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);
    saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

    if(arquivo != NULL){

        while(fgets(buffer, TAM_BUFFER, arquivo)){
            if(linecounter==2){
                strncpy(buffer2,buffer,sizeof buffer2 - 1);
                buffer2[sizeof buffer2 - 1] = '\0';
            }

            if (strncmp(buffer,"NEWDAY",strlen("NEWDAY")) == 0){
                fclose(saida);
                linecounter = 1;
                filecounter++;
                sscanf(buffer2, "%s", &buffer3);
                printf("strlen(%s)=%d\n", buffer3, (int) strlen(buffer3));
                sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer3);
                saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
                if (!saida)
                    return 1;       
            }

            fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer);
            linecounter++;

        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    fclose(saida);
    return 0;
}
```

*The thing i wanna do is get the second line of the file and use the first 14 characters as the name of the file.

The input of the file is this one:

```
TAM 2000-03-07T14:00    22.78   5.50999 2   786 2.8 798 2.8 186 0.0 298 3.2
TAM 2000-03-08T14:01    22.78   5.50999 2   779 1.2 793 1.0 186 0.0 300 1.5
TAM 2000-03-07T14:02    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:03    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:04    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-17T14:05    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:06    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
NEWDAY
TAM 2000-03-08T14:09    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:10    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:11    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-09T14:12    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
NEWDAY
TAM 2000-03-09T14:13    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-31T14:14    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:15    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:16    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:17    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:18    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-02T14:19    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
```

Comment: Can you please show us the input you try to parse.

Comment: Also, what is really the purpose of doing `sscanf(buffer2, "%s", &buffer3)`, except to get the first space-delimited "word"? If that's not the purpose then the `sscanf` call is just a bad way of doing `strcpy(buffer3, buffer2)`.

Comment: Hello Joachim, you tried to help me with this one before i have followed your instructions and decided use the sscanf after some tests. Now i am able to read the instructions but only until the first space. The input is 

TAM 2000-03-07T14:00 22.78 5.50999 2 786 2.8 798 2.8 186 0.0 298 3.2 and i wanna read until TAM 2000-03-07, but it is stopping in TAM

Comment: when i do strcpy, it does not work. The buffer3 gets the value of the buffer2 but it just dont rename the file. I mean, the fileoutputname receives nothing from the buffer3. The file is not even created.

Comment: Then the contents of `buffer2` should already contain the string you want. Have you tried printing out the contents of `buffer2`?

Comment: BTW `sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);` : `buffer2` isn't initialized.

Comment: Yes, buffer2 contains exactly the content i want.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, i did not understand. Why it is not initialized? How do i initialize the buffer2?

Comment: I taik about `char buffer2[15];
char buffer3[15];

FILE *arquivo = fopen("Entrada.txt", "r");
FILE *saida;

sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);
saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");`

Comment: Oh sorry, ok, that line is to make the first cycle. What happens is that everytime the day changes, we have a message of "NEWDAY" and when it is found, i split the file so the first line of the first file has the characters i want but from the second file until the end, the first line contais "NEWDAY" and not the data of the day. I am trying to fix the other files first, the first i have an idea of how to do it. That is why i used  if(linecounter==2){
        strncpy(buffer2,buffer,sizeof buffer2 - 1);
        buffer2[sizeof buffer2 - 1] = '\0';
        }

Comment: Why do `linecounter = 1;` inside `if (strncmp(buffer,"NEWDAY",strlen("NEWDAY")) == 0){` block.

Comment: Because once the file is splited and closed, i need to return an start counting the lines again since i will be interested in the second line of the next file and not in the first.

Comment: But read from same file(`arquivo`) :  `while(fgets(buffer, TAM_BUFFER, arquivo)){

        if(linecounter==2){` ...

Comment: Can you add to the question is an example of the contents of a specific each file?

Comment: Huum... i haven't paid attention to it. You can be right, after the from the second file until the end, it will take the first line. What i don't want...

Comment: Q1) `NEWDAY` itself is not included in the exported file?  Q2) In the example the same output file name. E.g `NEWDAY TAM 2000-03-07` In this case the contents of the previous file is lost.

Comment: Q3) Does blank line exists in the file? E.g `NEWDAY` <blank line> `TAM 2000-03-07...`

Comment: A1) Yes, `NEWDAY` is included on the exported file. The first row of the first exported file will contains `TAM 2000-03-07T14:00 22.78 5.50999 2 786 2.8 798 2.8 186 0.0 298 3.2` and from the second file until the end, the first row will contains `NEWDAY`. A2) I undestand your question, but it is a test input only, the real one has 16 millions of rows. In the real file, after `NEWDAY` the date will never be the same of the day before, `NEWDAY` appears when the date changes, so there is no chance of one file overwrite the other.

Comment: A3) No blank lines in the file.

Comment: `sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);` causes undefined behaviour because `buffer2` is uninitialized

Comment: `TAM_BUFFER` is too short by 1 to hold each line. (you forgot the *nul-terminating* character) and actually too short by 2 (your forgot the `'\n'` you will have to deal with with `fgets`)

Comment: @M.M i have to solve this problem later, as i told before, i am trying to solve the loop problem. This row is only for the first file where i do not have, in it's first row, the `NEWDAY`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well i will check it, the thing is that i do not need all these  parameters, so the last two columns doesn't matter too much for me, that is why i used fixed numbers. The thing is that if i wanted to split it with a generic name like doing: `sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d.txt", filecounter);` for example, it would work perfectly. But i need the date, there is the second row of each generated files. So i used `buffer2` to copy the first 14 characters of `buffer` and then did `buffer2[14]='\0'` to have the nul-terminating character and then use it in...

Comment: ...`sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", buffer2);` but it did not worked, the file was not even created and that was the reason i tried to create it with sscanf. With sscanf it worked well but the problem is that it ends at the first space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments you have a number of strings that are too long for the arrays you have declared. Specifically, your data file lines are `75` chars long and will not fit in a `75` char buffer. Make that change and adjusting the variable names a bit, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { BUFL = 20, TAMB = 80 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int fcnt = 1, lcnt = 1;
    char buf[TAMB] = "", buf2[BUFL] = "", buf3[BUFL] = "";
    char ofn[BUFL] = "";
    FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    FILE *ofp = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : stdout;
    if (!ifp || !ofp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, TAMB, ifp)) {
        char *p = buf;
        for (; *p && *p !='\n'; p++) {} /* remove trailing \n */
        if (*p) *p = 0; /* overwrite '\n' with nul-terminator */

        if (lcnt == 2) {
            strncpy (buf2, buf, BUFL - 1);
            buf2[BUFL - 1] = 0;
        }

        if (strncmp (buf, "NEWDAY", strlen("NEWDAY")) == 0) {
            fclose (ofp);
            lcnt = 1;
            fcnt++;
            // sscanf (buf2, "%s", &buf3);
            strcpy (buf3, buf2);
            printf ("strlen (%s) = %zu\n", buf3, strlen (buf3));
            sprintf (ofn, "%s.txt", buf3);
            ofp = fopen (ofn, "w");
            if (!ofp)
                return 1;       
        }
        fprintf (ofp, "%s\n", buf);
        lcnt++;
    }

    if (ifp != stdin) fclose (ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat dat/newday.txt
TAM 2000-03-07T14:00    22.78   5.50999 2   786 2.8 798 2.8 186 0.0 298 3.2
TAM 2000-03-08T14:01    22.78   5.50999 2   779 1.2 793 1.0 186 0.0 300 1.5
TAM 2000-03-07T14:02    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:03    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:04    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-17T14:05    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:06    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
NEWDAY
TAM 2000-03-08T14:09    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:10    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-07T14:11    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-09T14:12    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
NEWDAY
TAM 2000-03-09T14:13    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-31T14:14    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:15    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:16    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:17    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:18    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-02T14:19    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
```

**Example Use/Output Files**

```
$ ./bin/readspaces dat/newday.txt dat/newdayout.txt
strlen (TAM 2000-03-08T14:0) = 19
strlen (TAM 2000-03-08T14:0) = 19

$ cat dat/newdayout.txt
TAM 2000-03-07T14:00    22.78   5.50999 2   786 2.8 798 2.8 186 0.0 298 3.2

TAM 2000-03-08T14:01    22.78   5.50999 2   779 1.2 793 1.0 186 0.0 300 1.5

TAM 2000-03-07T14:02    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-07T14:03    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-07T14:04    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-17T14:05    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-07T14:06    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9


$ cat TAM\ 2000-03-08T14\:0.txt
NEWDAY

TAM 2000-03-09T14:13    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-31T14:14    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-01T14:15    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-01T14:16    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-01T14:17    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-01T14:18    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9

TAM 2000-03-02T14:19    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
```

(**note:** the additional lines are present because your failed to trim the `'\n'` read and included in `buf` by `fgets`)

After fixing the newline problem, your output files are:

```
$ cat TAM\ 2000-03-08T14\:0.txt
NEWDAY
TAM 2000-03-09T14:13    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-31T14:14    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:15    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:16    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:17    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:18    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-02T14:19    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
```

Look over the changes and let me know if you have any questions. It was unclear what length you were trying to achieve with the buffer2/3 size, but you can adjust the `BUFL` constant to make it what every suits your needs. Notice also, you can simply copy `buffer2` to `buffer3`, there is no need for a `snprintf` statements.

---

It does appear the `15` spaced produces the desired results for the `outputfilename` portion of the code. Changing `BUFL` to `15` provides:

```
$ ./bin/readspaces dat/newday.txt dat/newdayout.txt
strlen (TAM 2000-03-08) = 14
strlen (TAM 2000-03-08) = 14
```

and then produces the output file:

```
$ cat TAM\ 2000-03-08.txt
xt
TAM 2000-03-09T14:13    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-31T14:14    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:15    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:16    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:17    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-01T14:18    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
TAM 2000-03-02T14:19    22.78   5.50999 2   773 3.0 788 3.8 186 0.1 300 0.9
```

(**note:** however, a bit of undefined behavior as `NEWDAY` at the beginning of the output file is not `xt`)

Comment: Hey @David, what this part of the code means?  `FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    FILE *ofp = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : stdout;`

Shouldn`t you tell the input file?

Comment: That's just a way to *either* open and read from the filename given as `argv[1]` (*or* read from `stdin` if no filename is given) and to write to the file given by `argv[2]` if the filename is given by the second argument (or to `stdout` by default). It is a lazy man's way to test by sending output to the screen to confirm it is what your want before actually giving a filename and writing to the file `:)` Both make use of the *ternary* operator (e.g. `a = test ? <if true value> : <if false value>;`) A shorthand `if, else`. Useful in many many different situations.

Comment: It allows you to use the form `./bin/readspaces dat/newday.txt dat/newdayout.txt` to read/write to files, or, for example, `./bin/readspaces <dat/newday.txt` to dump the output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to let go of `sscanf()`, you could do it with `fgets()` instead..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer2[200] = "Name with Spaces";

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fmemopen (buffer2, strlen (buffer2), "r"); 

    char str[200];
    if ( fgets(str, 200, fp) != NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Scanned Name: %s \n", str );
    }
}
```

Comment: And then use the str inside the `sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", str);` ?

Comment: Yes, make sure `fileoutputname` is large enough and I think you should be good to go.

Comment: You probably want to remove `\n` from fgets buffer

Comment: well i have already done it with the `Buffer`, then i just copied the first 14 characters of this `Buffer` to `Buffer 2` because i do not need all the characters. After this, i said the last character of `Buffer 2` is `'\0'` in order to obligate the `Buffer2` to end at the 14th character. Then i did what you said, used `Buffer2` as the `str` in the `sprintf(fileoutputname, "%s.txt", str);` but it did not worked, the file was not even created and that was the reason i tried to create it with `sscanf`. With `sscanf` it worked well but the problem is that it ends at the first space character.

Comment: looking at your code, you might need to use `fmemopen` to get the data into the Filepointer `fp` in my code example.
`FILE *fp;`
    `fp = fmemopen (buffer2, strlen (buffer2), "r");`
    `fgets(buffer3,200,fp);`
    `close(fp);`
reads` buffer2` into `buffer3`.

Comment: Alright i will try to implement it. First i will take a look to how do i use the fmemopen, never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int TAM_BUFFER = 75; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char fileoutputname[15] = {0};
    char buffer[TAM_BUFFER];

    FILE *arquivo = fopen("Entrada.txt", "r");
    FILE *saida;

    if(arquivo == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(arquivo, "%14c", fileoutputname);//first split file name
    saida = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
    rewind(arquivo);

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, arquivo)){
        if(strncmp(buffer,"NEWDAY", 6) == 0){ // strlen("NEWDAY") is 6
            long file_pos = ftell(arquivo);//or use fgetpos for large file, save file position
            fscanf(arquivo, "%14c", fileoutputname);//next file name
            fseek(arquivo, file_pos, SEEK_SET);//or use fsetpos (pair with fgetpos), restore file position
            saida = freopen(fileoutputname, "w", saida);//fclose(saida);saida=fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
        }
        fprintf(saida,"%s", buffer);//No add newline
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    fclose(saida);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still will have problems, input lines are `75` chars long. Make `TAM_BUFFER = 80;` and your fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sample is less than 70.

Comment: He must have changed input files, the ones I copied are exactly `75` chars per line. (I've posted the one I copied from the question) Maybe he did.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It appears to be blank in fact it is TAB (try Edit Link).  Either way, says that he will change.

Comment: use `fputs` better than `fprintf` in this case.